# Animating Map Layers

Tags: javascript, cesium, animation

Situation:
I am new(ish) to the web mapping scene and I have build a web-map using the Cesium API. The scene cycles through a series of 3D polygons representing heatmaps over time. I'm loading the layers as a GeoJSON and am using the Cesium clock to cycle through the layers. I'm styling the GeoJSON by attribute and am extruding the height from a different field. As the next layer is loaded the last one is removed. What I want to do is add a transition so that as the old layer is removed have the polygons shrink and as the new layer is added it grows. I have looked at a few different animation libraries like D3, Three.js, and Babylon.js for examples but I haven't really found anything like what I'm trying to do.

Question:
Does anyone know of anything that can help me add a transition animations to GeoJSON layers? Not opposed to anything, very willing to learn something new!

A bit of the Code:

```
    function initCesium() {
    viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer", {
        imageryProvider: new Cesium.ArcGisMapServerImageryProvider({
            url: 'https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer'
        }),
        requestRenderMode: true,
        clockViewModel: new Cesium.ClockViewModel(clock),
        shouldAnimate: true,
    });
    //add an event listener to convert each "tick" into a year and use yearly ticks to call new layer
    viewer.clock.onTick.addEventListener(function () {
        tickYear = Cesium.JulianDate.toIso8601(viewer.clock.currentTime).substr(0, 4);

        //this if loops checks to see if the year has changed
        if (clockYear === tickYear)
            return;
        clockYear = tickYear;

        //if the timeline or user tries to use an invalid year the clock will pass over it and go to 2004
        if (invalidYear.indexOf(clockYear) > -1) {
            viewer.clock.currentTime = Cesium.JulianDate.fromIso8601('2003-12-31');
            viewer.clock.shouldAnimate = true;
        } else {
            getLayer(clockYear);
            removeLayer();
        }
    });
}
    //remove all layers
    function removeLayer() {
        viewer.dataSources.removeAll();
    }

    //add layer from clockYear and style the layer based on the entity properties.
    function getLayer(year) {
        //build geojson source from year
        promise = Cesium.GeoJsonDataSource.load('datasource part 1' + year + 'datasource part 2');
        promise.then(function (dataSource) {
            viewer.dataSources.add(dataSource);
            var entities = dataSource.entities.values;
            var colorhash = {};
            var totalCount = 0;
            var hashCount = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < entities.length; i++) {
                //create variables to store and generate colours
                var entity = entities[i];
                var name = entity.properties.Name;
                var color = colorhash[name];
                var outcolor;
                var symID = entity.properties.SymbolID;
                totalCount += entity.properties.Count;
                hashCount += 1;
                if (!color) {
                    if (symID == 0) {
                        color = Cesium.Color.DARKGREEN;
                        outcolor = Cesium.Color.DARKGREEN;
                        colorhash[name] = color;
                    } else if (symID == 1) {
                        color = Cesium.Color.ORANGE;
                        outcolor = Cesium.Color.ORANGE;
                        colorhash[name] = color;
                    } else if (symID == 2) {
                        color = Cesium.Color.ORANGERED;
                        outcolor = Cesium.Color.ORANGERED;
                        colorhash[name] = color;
                    } else {
                        color = Cesium.Color.MAROON;
                        outcolor = Cesium.Color.MAROON;
                        colorhash[name] = color;
                    }
                }
                entity.polygon.material = color;
                entity.polygon.outlineColor = outcolor;
                //extrude height base on count, can be adjusted if nessecary 
                entity.polygon.extrudedHeight = entity.properties.Count * 20;
            }
        }).otherwise(function (error) {
            window.alert(error);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a new Cesium Sandcastle, similar to this one: https://sandcastle.cesium.com/index.html?src=GeoJSON%2520and%2520TopoJSON.html (you will have to upload your GeoJSON somewhere or provide a dummy/generic GeoJSON).
Also, please share the relevant parts of your code here on gis.SE to give context to your question. :)

Comment: Ive added a bit of code there. Unfortunately, I cannot share a GeoJSON due to the privacy sensitivity of the data. Let me know if you need any other information!

Answer (score 0):

I envisage a logic using [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval). Make extrusion higher every x ms. The same has to be done in reverse when the layer exits the map, of course.

```
let i = 0
const extrusion = setInterval(() => {
    i++
    entity.polygon.extrudedHeight = entity.properties.Count * i;
  if (i>=50) clearInterval(extrusion);
}, 25);
```

A mocked-up example can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/newluck77/thxrcgzm/

Comment: Interesting approach! the JSfiddle works exactly how i would like mine to work but when I add it in the map doesnt load. I'm working in NetBeans 8.1 and i dont think it supports ES6 so i had to change const to var and "()=>" to "function()". I'm going to keep messing around with it and see if i can get it to work! Thanks so much.

Comment: Given that you use Promises (an ES6 feature), I thought that you also use the other ES6 features. :)

Comment: I didnt catch that! You're totally right, but now I'm even more confused as to why this code isn't working. I've got the layers to load but its very slow and doesnt extrude my larger layers. I'll continue tinkering with it and see what i come up with